# How to get hold of Response Object in StrongLoop(LoopBack)

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

I need to log the request Parameters that comes to LoopBack Server and Log Response Parameters that goes out of LoopBack Server.

Currently , I am able to log and get request information for remote hooks but unable to fetch response information, does any one have idea regarding this.

For Example

```
Claim.afterRemote('updateByClaimNumber', function (ctx, claim, next) {
    var util = Claim.app.models.ModelsUtil;
    util.createInvocationLogs(ctx);
    next();
  });
```

Here ctx, has the request and response but not fetching response infor like response headers, body and statuscode.

Is there any other way of getting this information, I tried creating a middle ware to get request and response but cannot get it working.

Answer (score 0):

At afterRemote hook you can only get response body as `claim` func argument, while response status and headers and not yet set.

You should listen for `res.on('finish')` [event](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish) to get all response data.